# Remove "Contents" header on first page after TOC

Tags: header-footer

I am using the `amsbook` document class.

My document has no chapters, but I'd like all even pages to have "Title" as opposed to the current chapter.  I've achieved this for all even pages (but one) by putting `\chaptermark{Title}` right after `\begin{document}\maketitle\tableofcontents`, assigning a "chapter" title for the entire document. However, the first page after the TOC is still displaying the "contents" header at the top of the page. Thereafter, the headers are as desired. Any suggestions?

**Edit:** The only extra information a minimal working example provides is the packages I am using, which is why I didn't originally include one. But hopefully this it where the problem is coming from.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{}
\makeindex[columns=2, title=Index]

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chaptermark{Title}

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum

\section{Section 3}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Here are screenshots of the top of the first few pages after the table of contents of this code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the minimal working example?

Comment: @Johannes_B See my edit.

Comment: You are simply doing it wrong. You need to use chapters, not sections.

Comment: Nope. I want the title as the header on even pages, and the current section on odd pages. So unless you have a way to assist in that way, please save your salty comments.

Comment: Amsbook uses chapters as the highest sectioning level. Sections are one level below.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. However, I’d like to take advantage of the feature that puts the current section as the header on the odd pages, and then put the title of the document on all the even ones. I only have sections in my document. If I were to change all the sections to chapters, and so obtain the current chapter in the header, is there still a way to put the main title on every other page?

Comment: Yes. I don't have time right now. You should update the MWE in the question to use chapters instead and ask how to get the title of the book on odd pages.